# Get image by ObjectId instead of image_name in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, flask

In my flask app, I am trying to retrieve the image I stored in the MongoDB GridFS. However, the only tool that I could find is `mongo.send_file(filename)` and it seems like this function only support getting image using filename.

Due to the fact that I have different images with the same name, I was wondering if there is anyway to retrieve the image using the unique ObjectId of the image file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been dealing with this issue as well. I resorted to modifying the send_file function on the flask API. Take a look at what I did here:

```html
from flask import current_app, request
from werkzeug.wsgi import wrap_file

from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from gridfs import GridFS, NoFile


def retrieve_image(file_id, mongo):
    storage = GridFS(mongo.db, "fs")

    try:
        fileobj = storage.get(file_id=ObjectId(file_id))
    except NoFile:
        #404
        print()

        # mostly copied from flask/helpers.py, with
        # modifications for GridFS
    data = wrap_file(request.environ, fileobj, buffer_size=1024 * 255)
    response = current_app.response_class(
        data,
        mimetype=fileobj.content_type,
        direct_passthrough=True,
        )
    response.content_length = fileobj.length
    response.last_modified = fileobj.upload_date
    response.set_etag(fileobj.md5)
    response.cache_control.max_age = 31536000
    response.cache_control.public = True
    response.make_conditional(request)
    return response
```

Mongo in the function is the flask_pymongo object. Let me know if I can clear anything up!